# Error: Caused by: com.sun.jna.platform.win32.COM.COMException: Class not registered(HRESULT: 80040154) (puArgErr=)

Tags: java, winapi, windows-10, comexception, comobject

I'm running my java spring application's test cases on my WIN 10 machine and I started to see these errors, is there any way to avoid these COM errors /workaround?

`Caused by: com.sun.jna.platform.win32.COM.COMException: Class not registered(HRESULT: 80040154) (puArgErr=)`

Comment: Many COM objects need to be registered before they can be accessed. As the error says: the object you are trying to create is not registered. Possible side cause: your client is x86 and the object is registered for x64 or the reverse. In other terms it's a deployment/setup issue  https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=80040154